# Are work-related questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, asking-questions

I'm still at University, but I would really like to know if it is possible to find any work related to DSP where I live (Buenos Aires, Argenitna). I don't think South America is the right place to look for a job like that, though.

Nevertheless, I wanted to post a question in dsp.SE asking for some recommendations and stuff, but then realized that it might be off-topic. Thus this question: **are work-related questions on-topic** (as long as they are associated with signal processing, of course)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that would be considered off-topic. Check out [this explanation of what is on-topic here.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

I suspect that such a question is probably off-topic for most Stack Exchange sites.

My only suggestion would be to use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1090/post-processing), which you already know about.